# Does PHP have non-short-circuting comparison operators?

Tags: php, operators, short-circuiting

I recently came across a bug in some code at work where a series of function calls were aggregated into a single success condition.  Something like

```
$success = true;
foreach($foo as $f) {
   $success = $success && do_foo($f);
}
```

The bug is do_foo() was intended to run across the entire collection (it has side-effects). but the && operator short-circuts and once once a false is encountered do_foo isn't called on the remainder of the collection.  Easy enough to refactor, but it led me to wondering:

**Does PHP have a logical operator that does not short-circut?**

Edit: Let me be clear, I'm not asking how to solve the bug. This is a hypothetical question about syntax.

Comment: In some limited testing I found the bitwise operators (&, |) work as such in this case, similar to other languages. But with PHP's weirdness when it comes to type juggling and [non-transitive operators](http://phpsadness.com/sad/52), I'm not satisfied.

Comment: Would it make sense just to put `do_foo()` first in this case?

Comment: In short: no, PHP does not have non-short-circuiting logical operators, because you can always write code that works as you expect even with short-circuiting operators (just put `do_foo` first here), and why have two sets of operators for such limited edge cases?

Comment: short-circuiting logical operators is one of those basic optimizations of code.  I can't imagine PHP has consciously made their code deliberately slower by having to go through all logical operations when it doesn't have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no dedicated operator for this purpose, but you have the choice of doing whacky stuff like this (assuming `do_foo($f)` always returns a boolean:

```
$success &= do_foo($f);
```

The outcome will be a numeric 0 or 1 instead of a boolean, but when used in a condition it shouldn't matter.

If the function doesn't always return a boolean or if the above is too unsettling:

```
$success = (bool)($success & do_foo($f));
```

#### Recommendation

That said, `do_foo($f)` should be run unconditionally and its return value used in the next statement.

Comment: Your first option does not return a boolean, even if the 'operands' are both booleans.

Comment: @nl-x Yeah, but it will evaluate to `true`; perhaps that could be made more obvious :)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because until someone contradicts you, saying "There's no dedicated operator for this purpose" satisfies the question.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need it? Just do it like this:

```
$success = true;
foreach($foo as $f) {
   $foo_done = do_foo($f);
   $success = $success && $foo_done;
}
```

**edit:**

I can think of one work around where in stead of `&&` I can use multiplication `*` and cast to boolean:

```
$success = (bool)($success * do_foo($f));
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with the code I encountered; this is a question about the language itself